# Flutter background color not changing

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I need your help for solving the first issue.

This is the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Login'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.

    final emailField = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Email",
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final passwordField = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Contraseña",
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final loginButon = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text("Entrar",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: style.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(66.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 185.0,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/logo_capenergy.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                    emailField,
                    SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                    passwordField,
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 35.0,
                    ),
                    loginButon,
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And this is a screenshot from the Flutter app:

[image]

I am not able to remove or hide the bottom background darker zone.

Comment: Wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with an `Expanded Widget` and lets see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your color in the Container but in the Scaffold:

```
 Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white
            ...
```